# Unable to use Chrome Experimental Devtools API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the Chrome Experimental Devtools API.

I've tried running Chrome with: --enable-experimental-extension-apis as suggested here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.html and enabled the "Experimental Extension APIs" in the flags settings.

When I open the Console in Chrome (or Canary), I get the following:

- chrome.devtools: undefined
- chrome.experimental: undefined

I'm running Chrome 21.0.1180.77 beta-m. I've also tried Canary.

What am I missing?

Comment: I had the same problem, I'm not sure how you fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools.html, the chrome.devtools APIs are only available in your devtools HTML page.

First, you need to create an HTML file and then add it to your extension's manifest under the "devtools_page" key.  When you load your extension into Chrome and open the DevTools, you should see your new tab.

In that tab is the only place chrome.devtools will work.

chrome.experimental is different and will be available in all of your background pages and content scripts.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me understanding the chrome.devtools. Does it mean that I should be able to use chrome.experimental from the devtools console?

Comment: Would I be able to use these methods without using them from a Chrome extension? I would like to use them from my webpage to store changes made to css and script files.

Comment: @Martin, no, it’s only for extensions.

Comment: @James [experimental.devtools.console](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.devtools.console.html) and [experimental.devtools.audits](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.devtools.audits.html) do work on a DevTools page, not background page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it only in Canary.
Plus when you run chrome add this flag to the command line:

```
path_to_chrome.exe --enable-experimental-extension-apis
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried this command: "C:\Users\mth\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --enable-experimental-extension-apis - It doesnt work.

Comment: What version of Chrome you are running?

Comment: So try Canary - my current version is: 23.0.1239.0

Comment: Alternatively you can enable the flag in chrome://flags/ (look for "Experimental Extension APIs" option)

Comment: Yury, If you read the question again, you can see that I already enabled that. Ido, my Canary version is: 23.0.1240.0. Do I need to downgrade? If yes, do you know where I can find the older version? I installed mine from this page: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/