# How to implicitly log a JavaScript object as a string?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Consider:

```
var o = { a: 1, b: 2, toString: function() { return "foo"; } };
```

In Chrome dev tools:

[image: Debug Screenshot]

Is there anything I could do to the object such that `o` is displayed in the debug console as `"foo"` instead of the full object?

Comment: `.toString()` is not good enough? I mean, if you want the return value of `o.toString` the easiest and cleanest way is calling it as you've done.

Comment: By comparison, in .NET, overriding `ToString()` will use it implicitly when debugging, even when you don't call `.ToString()`.  I want to know if the same effect is possible in JavaScript somehow.

Comment: You could easily overload `console.log`, but I'm thinking about the side-effects.

Comment: Well you could cast it `''+o`

Comment: @elclanrs - thanks, that's close - but I want a way to put this *inside* the object so it is cast implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt:

```
(function() {
    var cl = console.log;
    console.log = function() {
        cl.apply(console, [].slice.call(arguments).map(function(el) {
            return {}.toString.call(el) === '[object Object]' && typeof el.toString === 'function' && el.toString !== Object.prototype.toString ? el.toString() : el;
        }));
    };
}());
```

^ Just throw this script before any `console.log` call.

---

### [Test case:](http://jsfiddle.net/wf9HT/)

```
console.log('str', 42, /rege?x/, { a: 1 }, [1, 2], {
        toString: function() { return "foo"; }
    }, new function() {
        this.toString = function() {
            return 'bar';
        };
    }
);
```

[image: console.log output]

---

This just maps plain/constructed objects which have a `toString` method different from `Object.prototype.toString` to their `.toString()` value. I chose this way over `hasOwnProperty` as constructors may also have a `toString` method in their prototype.

As you can see, all objects and even primitives inherit a `toString` method from the native constructors, so you may need tweaking for specific use cases. The snippet above does not stringify function objects with custom `toString` properties, for example.

Comment: This should suffice for all common use cases that I can think of. Feel free to comment if you manage to find any bugs with it.

Comment: Nice attempt, this is pretty close - except you still have to call `console.log(o)` instead of just `o`.  I guess the debug window doesn't go through console.log directly?

Comment: Also, I was really hoping for something I could put *inside* the object so it was wired up but wouldn't affect everything globally.  Perhaps that is just not possible in JS?

Comment: @MattJohnson Oh I see, thought you were referring to `console.log` which is often used from inside the code, as for entering it directly on Dev Tools it can't be solved with plain JS I believe. Maybe it is possible to extend or override certain parts of the Dev Tools (I've seen extensions that extend the Firebug console but not sure if there's an API to extend the Dev Tools console).

Comment: This *may* be possible with [`chrome.experimental.devtools.console`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_console.html), I'll check whether I can get something useful out of it. `=]`

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for checking.  Not a critical issue or anything, so don't sweat it.

Comment: Yup no worries, experimenting with extensions is fun too. But apparently the `devtools.*` APIs can only be used inside a new dev tools tab created by the extension ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12049096/1331430)), so I guess it'd need an extra tab to listen to console messages and then send new messages. Doesn't sound too appealing.

Comment: Yep, the API is very limited. It is possible to listen to console messages without creating a new DevTools tab, however the API doesn't suffice for this use case: 1. It is not possible to prevent or edit already posted console messages, you can only listen to messages and post new console messages; 2. It only works for messages sent natively or through the `console` API, if you simply enter a command in the console it isn't caught by the listener; 3. You get the result of console.log's first argument's `.toString()` only, you can't examine object properties nor pass multiple arguments.